# Plugin authoring: How to allow $.myPlugin.defaults.key = 'value';?

Tags: jquery, plugins

## Original question:

*Note: Below plugin pattern based on [the official jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).*

I'm stuck... How can I convert the below plugin pattern to allow `$.hooplah.defaults.whoop = 'there it was';`?

```
;(function($) {

    var config = {};

    config.defaults = {
        foo   : 'bar',
        hey   : 'ho',
        whoop : 'there it is'
    };

    $.fn.hooplah = function(method) {

        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.hooplah.');
        }

    };

    var methods = {

        init: function(opts) {

            return this.each(function() {

                var options = $.extend({}, config.defaults, opts);

                // Stuff here...

            });

        }

    };

})(jQuery);
```

Optimally, I would like to do both `$('.foo').hooplah({ whoop: 'there is was' })` and `$.hooplah.defaults.whoop = 'there it was';`.

Any tips/code/links would be greatly appreciated. :)

Many thanks in advance for the help!

---

## Proposed solution #1

### Calling syntax: `$.pluginName.defaults`

Code based on **@AmithGeorge's** reply:

```
;(function($) {

    var config = {};

    config.others = {
        blah : 'nah',
        cha  : 'right!',
        last : 'one'
    }

    config.defaults = {
        foo   : 'bar',
        hey   : 'ho',
        whoop : 'there it is'
    };

    $.hooplah = {};
    $.hooplah.defaults = config.defaults;
    $.hooplah.others   = config.others;

    $.fn.hooplah = function(method) {

        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.hooplah.');
        }

    };

    var methods = {

        init: function(opts) {

            return this.each(function() {

                var defaults = $.extend({}, config.defaults, config.others, $.hooplah.defaults, $.hooplah.others);

                // After some lines...

                var options = $.extend({}, defaults, opts);

                console.log(options);

                // Stuff here...

            });

        }

    };

})(jQuery);
```

#### HTML:

```
<ul id="nav><li>...</li></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $.hooplah.defaults.foo = 'foooooo';
            $.hooplah.defaults     = { whoop : 'what?' };
            $.hooplah.others.blah  = 'why?';
            $.hooplah.others       = { cha : 'ok' }
            $nav = $('#nav');
            $nav.hooplah({
                hey  : 'hey hey',
                last : 'first'
            });

        });

    //-->
</script>
```

#### Output before:

```
blah     "nah"
cha      "right!"
foo      "bar"
hey      "ho"
last     "one"
whoop    "there it is"
```

#### Output after:

```
blah     "why?"
cha      "ok"
foo      "foooooo"
hey      "hey hey"
last     "first"
whoop    "what?"
```

---

## Proposed solution #2

### Calling syntax: `$.fn.pluginName.defaults`

Code based on **@JonJaques** reply:

```
;(function($) {

    var config = {};

    config.others = {
        blah : 'nah',
        cha  : 'right!',
        last : 'one'
    }

    config.defaults = {
        foo   : 'bar',
        hey   : 'ho',
        whoop : 'there it is'
    };

    var methods = {

        init: function(opts) {

            return this.each(function() {

                var options = $.extend({}, config.defaults, config.others, $.fn.hooplah.defaults, $.fn.hooplah.others, opts);

                console.log(options);

                console.log(config.others.last); // Outputs "one".

                // Stuff here...

            });

        }

    };

    $.fn.hooplah = function(method) {

        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.hooplah.');
        }

    };

    $.fn.hooplah.defaults = config.defaults;

    $.fn.hooplah.others = config.others;

})(jQuery);
```

#### HTML:

```
<ul id="nav><li>...</li></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $nav = $('#nav');

            $.fn.hooplah.defaults.foo = 'foooooo';
            $.fn.hooplah.defaults     = { whoop : 'what?' };
            $.fn.hooplah.others.blah  = 'why?';
            $.fn.hooplah.others       = { cha : 'ok' }
            $nav.hooplah({
                hey  : 'hey hey',
                last : 'first'
            });

        });

    //-->
</script>
```

#### Output before:

```
blah     "nah"
cha      "right!"
foo      "bar"
hey      "ho"
last     "one"
whoop    "there it is"
```

#### Output after:

```
blah     "why?"
cha      "ok"
foo      "foooooo"
hey      "hey hey"
last     "first"
whoop    "what?"
```

---

**Awesome. :)**

*Let me know if the above code samples could be improved and/or if I overlooked something.*

Thank you @AmithGeorge and @JonJaques! You folks seriously **ROCK!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why cant you just do this?

```
config.defaults = {
    foo   : 'bar',
    hey   : 'ho',
    whoop : 'there it is'
};

$.hooplah.config.defaults = config.defaults;
```

And in your init function, the first line will be

```
var defaults = $.extend({}, config.defaults, $.hooplah.config.defaults);
// after some lines
var options = $.extend({}, defaults, opts);
```

The advantage I see of doing it this way is, if some one were to replace the $.hooplah.config.defaults with an object that doesnt have the same keys as your config, your plugin can still get the default config values from the private variable.

Comment: Thanks! Trying this now, I'll be back ASAP with my results.

Comment: Thanks again @amith! Your solution worked very well. I just had to add `$.hooplah = {};` in order for everything to work. I've updated my question to include the updated code/solution. Let me know if you have any feedback. Thank you!!!!

Comment: You want to assign to $.fn.hooplah   In jQuery   jQuery.fn is an alias for jQuery.prototype.  So anything you assign to $.fn will be available to as $.hooplah.

Comment: When we do $('selector').plugin(), it reads its options/methods from what is defined under $.fn.plugin. By default there is no auto mapping from $.fn.plugin to $.plugin. ... It's like how jQuery has $.each and $.fn.each. They have different signatures and serve different purposes. That said, the site wide settings could either be under $.fn.plugin.defaults or $.plugin.defaults. The few jquery plugins I have used, had it under $.plugin. Technically they both will work just fine.

Comment: @AmithGeorge I'm not sure I understand what you mean in your last comment... If it's not too much trouble, could you clarify? Do I need to change something in my code example(s)?

Comment: @JonJaques Thank you for the additional information, I really appreciate it! I've added both solutions to my original question, please let me know if you see something that could be better and/or more optimized.

Comment: @MickyHulse, no nothing needs to be changed in the sample 1. I was just saying both solutions can work. I prefer mine :).

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you confused about?

`config.defaults` is where *you* define the defaults.

`opts` (the arg passed into `init`) corresponds to the object that is passed into your plugin.

```
$('.foo').hooplah({
   whoop: 'there is was'
}
```

this overrides your default options, but doesn't erase 'foo' or 'hey'.

and inside `init` you want to refer to the `options` var, because this var represents the combination of the defaults that *you* set, and the options that the *user* specifies.

Does that answer your question?

In response to your comment - 
You could write

```
$.fn.hooplah = function(method) {
  this.defaults = config.defaults;
```

Then add $.fn.hooplah.defaults as the third argument to the extend function

```
var options = $.extend({}, config.defaults, $.fn.hooplah.defaults, opts);
```

Where `config.defaults` would be your private reference to the defaults,
`$.fn.hooplah.defaults`, would be a public overridable object where users could set "Global" config,
and `opts` would be the object that is passed in on a per-use basis.

And then you just reference the `options` variable everywhere else in your plugin code.

Comment: thanks! Your post have been very helpful. Optimally, I would like to do both `$('.foo').hooplah({ whoop: 'there is was' })` and `$.hooplah.defaults.whoop = 'there it was';`. :)

Comment: Oooh, interesting! Sorry I missed your updated comment. Now I'm wishing I could pick two answers as the solution! I'm going to play with your solution and post back my results. Thanks again!!! :)

Comment: No worries, let you know what you come up with.

Comment: I've updated my question to show your solution. Thanks! The only issue I ran into was with `$.fn.hooplah.defaults.blah` (I got `$.fn.hooplah.defaults is undefined` errors). Please let me know if I overlooked something. Thanks again! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: `this` does not point `to $.fn.hooplah`. `this` in that context refers to the jQuery object. Meaning, $('selector').plugin().defaults is the object you are referring to when you set `this.defaults = something`. Delete those two `this` lines. After your hooplah method definition is over, just before the `var methods = `, place these two lines: `$.fn.hooplah.defaults = config.defaults; $.fn.hooplah.others = config.others;` ... That will fix the undefined errors and make this plugin work :)

Comment: @AmithGeorge: WOOT! That did the trick! I've updated the code via my question to reflect those changes. JonJaques: I wish I could mark both replies as best answers because I really dig both approaches... Sorry about that. Thanks a billion to both of you for the pro help!!!! :)

Comment: @AmithGeorge, good call. I didn't have time to run this through a browser, which is how I tend to fix my problems :)

Comment: @MickyHulse Looks like both solutions seem to be working for you. As with most things, there's more than one way to setup plugins, its just what works best for you. Good luck!